# Calling a .bat from a setup.exe file

Tags: batch-file, exe

I am using 7zip to create a software setup package.  Everything works just fine except I need to stop and restart a service.  I can manipulate the service using the net stop / start commands using a .bat file but I want to have this file called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that 7z has the option of an **Installer Config** file - you add this to your installer using:

> copy /b 7zS.sfx + config.txt + archive.7z archive.exe

An example config file you could use:

> ;!@Install@!UTF-8!
>   Title="MyInstallation"
>   BeginPrompt="Ready to Install?"
>   ExecuteFile="cmd.exe"
>   ExecuteParameters="/c MyCommand.bat"
>   ;!@InstallEnd@!

Check the help file under *Command Line Version* > *Switches* > *-sfx (Create SFX archive)* for more details about the config file